# My non-inverting opamp circuit clips

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier

I want to amplify the DAC output of an Arduino MKR WiFi 1010 from a 0-3.3V range to 0-5V. After some research I decided to use a non-inverting amplifier, with an LM324, using a rail voltage the 5V of the Arduino itself.

[image: circuit]

The output looks like this, clipped at around 3,7V.

[image: clipped]

This is the input signal (max around 3.2V)

[image: original]

I reckoned I wouldn't be able to reach the full 5V, but I wasn't counting on this much loss. Is this normal, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't say what the supply rail to your LM324 is, but I'm guessing it's 5 V.  In that case it's perfectly normal per the datasheet, as the output can only swing to about 1.5 V below the supply rail. There are rail-to-rail output amplifiers that can get you much closer to 5 V so you might want to look for one of those or run your op-amp from a higher voltage.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, yes that is 5V.

Comment: "Large Output Swing".  Yes, by 1972 standards. The state of the art has advanced considerably.